# bash sort list of strings by number at the end

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a list of files with a version number at the end that I need to sort

```
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
```

when I pipe it through grep it sort like so:

```
echo $files | sort -n
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
```

I think the -n is getting confused by the first number in the file name.

How can I sort it numerically by the last number

Comment: Always the same depth of path?

Comment: yes, but I don't know the depth until I am trying to sort

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat ztestfile1 | sort -t'/' -n -k10
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
```

does this help ?

alternative way ie to be independent from the position .....

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test  $ cat ztestfile1 | sort -V
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
 /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
```

please note its a -V (Capital) option in sort that looks into numeric differences in a string to sort ..... like in version number .

man page text ::

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Comment: this is what I had been trying except that I was going by the man page and had extra spaces `sort -n -t '/' -k 10` and apparently sort doesn't like that

Comment: ohh ok , seems the issue is sorted now ... :)

Comment: Be aware that with this kind of solution you have to know and specify the depth of the files.

Comment: @michas I am passing the string through `tr '/' ' ' | wc -w` to determine the depth, it feels there should be a better way, but it works

Comment: Me too, The -V, this gives a true sorting when it comes to numbers, the others option groups the lines base on the number of digits in the numbers, which in my book is a faulty sorting :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `/` as a column separator:

```
sort -n -t/ -k 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk` to bring the last field to the front, `sort` by the 1st field, then apply `cut` to get rid of the first field. An example using a `here document` below

```
awk -F'/' '{print($NF"/"$0)}' <<! | sort -k1n,1n -t'/' | cut -f2- -d'/'
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
> /this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
> !
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/6
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/7
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/8
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/9
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/10
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/12
/this/is/a/file/path/product-2.0/file/name/13
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a one-liner something like perl or ruby:

```
ruby -we 'print *readlines.sort_by{|x| File.basename(x).to_i}'
```

Answer (score -1):

This gets you sorted by the last item in the path by using `/` as the field separator, taking the last value and placing it at the start of the line, sorting, then removing the value from the start of the line.

```
cat data | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"} { print $(NF) " " $0 }' | sort -n | sed 's/^.*\s//g'
```